# Problem with c++ sorting of objects, vectors

Tags: c++

Consider the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Vertex {
    public:
    int id;
    vector<Vertex*> edges;
    Vertex(int id) : id(id) {}
    int get_id() const {return id;}
};

class Graph {
    public:
    vector<Vertex*> vertices;
    Graph(int V) {
        vertices.reserve(V);
    }
    void test(vector<Vertex*>& other) {
        sort(vertices.begin(), vertices.end(), [](const Vertex*& one, const Vertex*& two) {return &*one < &*two;});
        sort(other.begin(), other.end(), [](const Vertex*& one, const Vertex*& two) {return &*one < &*two;});
    }
};
```

When I try to compile the above I get the error: `error: no matching function for call to object of type '(lambda at Graph.cpp:59:48)' if (__comp(*--__last, *__first))`. I don't understand how I can fix this issue.

Comment: You provide no way of comparing `Vertex` objects.

Comment: @sweenish but I don't compare any vertex objects? I only compare their memory addresses.

Comment: Why are you comparing adresses in your lambdas? Also why add the reference the pointers; you're not saving any space by using a reference to a pointer instead of a pointer.

Comment: @sweenish see the posted answer

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OP is trying to sort pointers by the addresses stored in them, not by their own addresses, it seems.

Comment: `&*one < &*two` confused me. I was thinking of `&one < &two`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux everything works fine. I wanted to sort them by their address so I can check whether the two vectors have any pointers that point to the same vertex object.

Comment: @Jacob *so I can check whether the two vectors have any pointers that point to the same vertex object* -- Then that begs the question -- what do you do if you found out there are pointers pointing to the same vertex?  In all honesty, your code looks like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) scenario.

Comment: @Jacob Beware that comparing addresses of objects is unspecified behavior, unless those objects are part of the same array or contiguous container or members of the same object. It will probably work as you expect but it may behave unexpectedly on some implementations. You should use [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) which correctly orders pointers on all platforms, even those whose `operator<` may not work that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters of your comparators are non-const references. More specifically, "references to non-const pointers to const `Vertex`".

You either need const references: `const Vertex *const &one`, or even better, just pass by value: `const Vertex *one`.

Also note that `&*one < &*two` is equivalent to `one < two`.

Comment: @Jacob You're welcome! You can press the checkmark on the left to mark your question as solved.

Comment: I'm aware of this, but one can only do this after a certain amount of minutes.